# Opencart Modification page shows 403 Forbidden error

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403, opencart-3

Modifications page which contain refresh button, shows

> 403 Forbidden nginx/1.14.0

chmod is 644

also I tried to re-upload the file `public_html/admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php`, but still shows the 403 error, I also tried a fresh install copy.

I've found that my server blocks this path `marketplace/modification`, is there any way to rename the modification page in Admin control panel?

I'm using 3.0.2.0 (Arabic codlance)

please help

Comment: styling, in general the question was already clear before.
Added tag `nginx`

Comment: my server blocks any path contains "marketplace/modification", any help please?

Comment: Is it possible that nginx-configuration prohibits access to that directory?

Comment: I'm on free hosting server, and I found that any path contain "modification" shows 403 error, So, is there any way to rename the file modification.twig?? or something else

Comment: is there any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file "modification.php" is hardcoded in many places, so there are only 3 possibilities:

1. Change the hoster
2. Contact the hoster and ask to allow the file modification.php and folders with names `modification` and `modifications`
3. Change the php-code and the file-name of modification.php to another name.

Assume you chose option 3, there still might be another problem because there exists still one or more folders `modifications` and perhaps also files with that name in plural or singular.
So if you want to keep that free hoster and also use opencart and additionally have no chance that the hoster is changing some settings for you, then you've to spend some time to change the code or perhaps some money to let someone do it for you.

Just an impression where `modification` is found as example, the list is still much longer:

[image]

**UPDATE**
There is still a chance that a file ".htaccess" exists on the server in your web-directory and that content of this file prohibits you from accessing all files and directories. Look in your web-directory and post the file if you find one.

Comment: I've found the file named modification.twig in this path /public_html/admin/view/template/marketplace/, and I succeed to rename it to another admin page, to "extension.twig", However the modification page shows in the new renamed page but refresh button won't work, it hasn't any hyperlink and just takes me to login admin page, is there any solution to fix the refresh button, modification.twig https://uploadfiles.io/ypzi8

Comment: sure, many many more changes. There are also `modification.php`, `modification.xml` and many more problems. Solving one by one keeps you busy for some time.

Comment: can you tell me please how to solve this problem because I'm beginner in Php?

Comment: As beginner you won't be able.

Comment: Check if you have a file ".htaccess", you still have a small chance that this is responsible for the strange server-behavior and you could change it

Comment: yes I've a file ".htaccess", and I'd tried to rename it, but the problem didn't solved

Comment: then if possible you should contact the hosting company

Comment: I'm trying to contact them, but if there is a way to add the refresh button code inside any other page without a uploading a modification file, please tell me about it

Comment: As your primary issue is answered please create a new question with the button-issue. I'd appreciate if you mark my answer as solution, perhaps even upvote it, but primary concern is not to mix up different issues, so that the portal keeps as clear as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Still, my primary issue unresolved, and I'm seeking now to found a solution to refresh modifications, I can't install new mods that need a refresh, is there any tip?

Comment: It's an individual problem and the required answers can be given only by the hosting-company. Alternatively you can change to another hosting-company.

Comment: is there any idea?